# Force Install Windows 7 on a 2017 Macbook Pro (Newer Macbook)

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup, install

I really want to BootCamp Windows 7 to my Macbook Pro 15-inch 2017.

The problem is that Boot Camp Assistant only takes Windows 10 64bit or newer. Tried editing the Info.plist numerous amount of times. I even tried Windows 7 installation images with UEFI created in them.

I was able to get far booting into the installation and after that finished, I booted into the Windows Drive using alt+option, and then it gave me a BSOD.

So im stuck there.

Plus, I do not like Windows 10 at all so please no comments telling me that installing Windows 10 is the end all be all solution and that Windows 7 cannot be installed on newer machines.

I am very welcome to experimenting and if you have any knowledge about UEFI/EFI and WinPE bootcamp drivers, I strongly believe we can get this working on a newer machine.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Win7 is not supported on any Mac after the 2014 models. In other words there are no *drivers* for your Mac that work with Windows 7.

Comment: why not try a Virtual Machine?

Comment: @SteveChambers There has to be a way to install Windows 10 drivers onto Windows 7 I know it can be done.

Comment: @SolarMike Because you don't get the full performance graphics experience as if you were Booting into the actual OS.

Comment: Good - YOU know it can be done, so post the solution as an answer. Be interested to read it.

Comment: @SolarMike I will soon .